# error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.66: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, debian, libraries, secure-crt, parrot-os

I installed as OS ParrotOS which is based on debian and installed securecrt which is my favorite SSH tool.

In the past it was no problem to start securecrt. but i did an OS upgrade and since then i am not able to start scrt. Then i tried to upgrade from securecrt from 8.5 to 9.0 but i get the same messages. i am not able to start this program anymore.

If i want to start via the menu the scrt-icon will be shown in the taskbar but it doesn't start and the icon does disappear after a certain time.
If i want to start securecrt via console i will get the message "SecureCRT: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.66: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I don't find any logs about the problem in /var/logs and didn't find any logs about securecrt everywhere else.
The tipps to reinstall libpythos, libssl, libjpeg i have done.
Also i purged and removed securecrt and reinstalled but problem is still there.

do you another tipps or can help please?

tree:

```
tree /usr/lib/scrt
/usr/lib/scrt
├── lib
│   ├── libQt5DBus.so.5
│   └── libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
├── libClientConfigUiQt.so
├── libCommonUiQt.so
├── libpython3Qt.so
├── libQt5Core.so.5
├── libQt5Gui.so.5
├── libQt5Multimedia.so.5
├── libQt5Network.so.5
├── libQt5PrintSupport.so.5
├── libQt5Widgets.so.5
└── plugins
    ├── platforminputcontexts
    │   ├── libcomposeplatforminputcontextplugin.so
    │   └── libibusplatforminputcontextplugin.so
    └── platforms
        └── libqxcb.so
```

dpkg.log:

```
2021-03-03 20:54:30 remove scrt:amd64 9.0.0-2430 <none>
2021-03-03 20:54:30 status half-configured scrt:amd64 9.0.0-2430
2021-03-03 20:54:30 status half-installed scrt:amd64 9.0.0-2430
2021-03-03 20:54:30 status config-files scrt:amd64 9.0.0-2430
2021-03-03 20:54:30 status not-installed scrt:amd64 <none>
2021-03-03 20:55:45 install scrt:amd64 <none> 9.0.0-2430
2021-03-03 20:55:45 status half-installed scrt:amd64 9.0.0-2430
2021-03-03 20:55:47 status unpacked scrt:amd64 9.0.0-2430
2021-03-03 20:55:47 configure scrt:amd64 9.0.0-2430 9.0.0-2430
2021-03-03 20:55:47 status half-configured scrt:amd64 9.0.0-2430
2021-03-03 20:55:47 status installed scrt:amd64 9.0.0-2430
2021-03-03 21:38:34 upgrade scrt:amd64 9.0.0-2430 9.0.0-2430
2021-03-03 21:38:34 status half-configured scrt:amd64 9.0.0-2430
2021-03-03 21:38:34 status unpacked scrt:amd64 9.0.0-2430
2021-03-03 21:38:34 status half-installed scrt:amd64 9.0.0-2430
2021-03-03 21:38:35 status unpacked scrt:amd64 9.0.0-2430
2021-03-03 21:38:35 configure scrt:amd64 9.0.0-2430 9.0.0-2430
2021-03-03 21:38:35 status half-configured scrt:amd64 9.0.0-2430
2021-03-03 21:38:35 status installed scrt:amd64 9.0.0-2430
```

```
┌─[xyz@parrot]─[/var/log]
└──╼ $sudo grep -rI --exclude="dpkg.log" "scrt" *
apt/history.log:Commandline: /usr/bin/apt remove -f scrt
apt/history.log:Remove: scrt:amd64 (9.0.0-2430)
apt/history.log:Commandline: /usr/bin/apt --purge remove scrt
apt/history.log:Purge: scrt:amd64 (9.0.0-2430)
apt/history.log:Commandline: /usr/bin/apt --purge remove scrt
apt/history.log:Purge: scrt:amd64 (9.0.0-2430)
apt/term.log:Entfernen von scrt (9.0.0-2430) ...
apt/term.log:Entfernen von scrt (9.0.0-2430) ...
apt/term.log:Entfernen von scrt (9.0.0-2430) ...
```

```
┌─[yz@parrot]─[/var/log]
└──╼ $sudo grep -rI --exclude="dpkg.log" "securecrt" *
┌─[✗]─[xyz@parrot]─[/var/log]
```

many thanks